# Hive is not supporting subquery, I need to get max date from self join table

Tags: python, sql, pyspark, hive, subquery

```sql
SELECT
    a.FIRST_NAME, a.LAST_NAME, a.MANAGER, a.MANAGER_CODE, a.EMPLOYEE_CODE, 
    b.FIRST_NAME AS MANAGER_FN, b.LAST_NAME AS MANAGER_LN, 
    c.FIRST_NAME AS DIRECTOR_FN, c.LAST_NAME AS DIRECTOR_LN
FROM
    emp_table a 
LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT DISTINCT manager_code, employee_code, first_name, last_name, end_date 
     FROM emp_table) AS b ON a.manager_code = b.employee_code
                          AND b.end_date = (SELECT MAX(end_date) FROM table)
LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT DISTINCT manager_code,employee_code, first_NAME, LAST_NAME, END_DATE 
     FROM emp_table) AS c ON b.manager_code = c.employee_code 
                          AND c.END_DATE = (SELECT MAX(end_date) FROM emp_table);
```

**ERROR**:

> Error while compiling statement: FAILED: SemanticException org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.optimizer.calcite.CalciteSubquerySemanticException: 0:0
> Unsupported SubQuery Expression Currently SubQuery expressions are only allowed as Where and Having Clause predicates.
> Error encountered near token 'end_date'

I am thinking it's failing at the `AND` portion of the `LEFT JOIN` condition in query.

Comment: Right.  Your query is too complicated for their SQL processor.  You will need to find a different way to do it.

Comment: why tag pyspark? Are you be able to run PySpark instead of Hive query?

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate max date in the same dataset without group by using analytic functions, then filter.

```
SELECT
    a.FIRST_NAME, a.LAST_NAME, a.MANAGER, a.MANAGER_CODE, a.EMPLOYEE_CODE, 
    b.FIRST_NAME AS MANAGER_FN, b.LAST_NAME AS MANAGER_LN, 
    c.FIRST_NAME AS DIRECTOR_FN, c.LAST_NAME AS DIRECTOR_LN
FROM
    emp_table a 
LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT DISTINCT manager_code, employee_code, first_name, last_name, end_date
       FROM
           (SELECT manager_code, employee_code, first_name, last_name, end_date,
                   max(end_date) over(partition by employee_code) as max_end_date
              FROM emp_table) b 
      WHERE b.end_date = b.max_end_date  --Filter
     ) c ON a.manager_code = b.employee_code
LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT DISTINCT manager_code,employee_code, first_NAME, LAST_NAME, END_DATE
       FROM
           (SELECT manager_code, employee_code, first_NAME, LAST_NAME, END_DATE,
                   MAX(end_date) over(partition by employee_code) as max_end_date 
            FROM emp_table) c
      WHERE c.end_date = c.max_end_date  --Filter
    ) c ON b.manager_code = c.employee_code 
                          ;
```

Comment: Thanks for modifying query its working with out error, but not returning max(end_date) record from table c & table d, there I am expecting 1 record for each employee when joining on manager_code = employee_code( employee will be more than 1 record with different end_date's).

Comment: @Ven Yes, probably max_date should be calculated in the employee_code partition rather than all the data Changed it in the answer, please check

Answer (score 0):

In general it would simplify the query to split up getting the most recent record from the subqueries.

If you are using pyspark as it is tagged here would suggest using the dataframe API to handle you joins, and transformations.  In general have found that to perform better than using spark.sql with complex queries.

#### Sample Source Data

```
{"first_name":"alfred", "last_name":"pennyworth", "manager":"dick grayson", "manager_code":"2", "employeecode":"1", "end_date":"12/1/2021"}
{"first_name":"alfred", "last_name":"pennyworth", "manager":"dick grayson", "manager_code":"2", "employeecode":"1", "end_date":"12/2/2021"}
{"first_name":"dick", "last_name":"grayson", "manager":"bruce wayne", "manager_code":"3", "employeecode":"2", "end_date":"12/2/2021"}
{"first_name":"bruce", "last_name":"wayne", "manager":"bob kane", "manager_code":"4", "employeecode":"3", "end_date":"12/2/2021"}
```

#### Sample Code

```
def get_current_records(df,partition_columns, order_column):
    """Removes duplicate records from a spark dataframe and returns the most recent record based on given partiion and order by column

    Args:
        df (spark dataframe): The dataframe we want to get the most recent records for 
        partition_columns (list): A list of columns to be used for getting the most recent record for. ( The group by columns)
        order_column (string): The column to order by

    Returns:
        spark dataframe: Dataframe that has had the logic applied to it
    """
    df = df.dropDuplicates() 
    df = df.withColumn("rn", row_number().over(Window.partitionBy(partition_columns).orderBy(col(order_column).desc())))
    df = df.filter(col("rn") == 1).drop("rn")
    return df 

employee_df = spark.read.json('tests/data/emp.json')
        
employee_df = get_current_records(employee_df, ['employeecode'], 'end_date')

employee_df = employee_df.alias('emp')\
            .join(employee_df.alias('manager'), (col('emp.manager_code') == col('manager.employeecode')), how='left')\
            .join(employee_df.alias('director'), (col('manager.manager_code') == col('director.employeecode')), how='left')\
            .select(\
                col('emp.first_name'),\
                col('emp.last_name'),\
                col('emp.manager'),\
                col('emp.manager_code'),\
                col('emp.employeecode'),\
                col('manager.first_name').alias('manager_first_name'),\
                col('manager.last_name').alias('manager_last_name'),\
                col('director.first_name').alias('director_first_name'),\
                col('director.last_name').alias('director_last_name')\
            )

employee_df.orderBy(col('emp.employeecode')).show(10,False)
```

This yields output of:

```
+----------+----------+------------+------------+------------+------------------+-----------------+-------------------+------------------+
|first_name|last_name |manager     |manager_code|employeecode|manager_first_name|manager_last_name|director_first_name|director_last_name|
+----------+----------+------------+------------+------------+------------------+-----------------+-------------------+------------------+
|alfred    |pennyworth|dick grayson|2           |1           |dick              |grayson          |bruce              |wayne             |
|dick      |grayson   |bruce wayne |3           |2           |bruce             |wayne            |null               |null              |
|bruce     |wayne     |bob kane    |4           |3           |null              |null             |null               |null              |
+----------+----------+------------+------------+------------+------------------+-----------------+-------------------+------------------+
```

A similar process could be handled using only hive by leveraging a hive view which gets the most recent records or persisting the most recent records.

The logic in the example also has an issue when trying to label the hierarchy given that a managers manager would be a director which is a separate problem.